# TypeError: descriptor 'fbind' requires a 'kivy._event.EventDispatcher' object but received a 'str'

Tags: python, kivy

I have just started to use kivy. Currently, I am watching videos on kivy and copying their code. I copied it but got an error while the dude in the video didnt. I am trying to make a moving Label and a textinput box.

This is my code:

```py
b = BoxLayout()
t = TextInput
f = FloatLayout()
s = Scatter()
l = Label(text="hell0")
f.add_widget(s)
s.add_widget(l)
b.add_widget(f)
b.add_widget(t)
```

this is the error im getting:

> TypeError: descriptor 'fbind' requires a 'kivy._event.EventDispatcher' object but received a 'str'

Comment: provide a [MRE]

Comment: do you want all of my code?

Comment: Look, when i launch the code with all of the import it gives me this error. In the video he got half of a screen with text input and half of the screen with the moving label. why does it not work for me? i return b

Comment: I do not know, if you want help then provide an MRE

Comment: i dont understand what it means

Comment: read [MRE], [ask] and review the [tour], bye.

Comment: this is my code from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class TutorialApp(App):
    def build(self):
        b = GridLayout()
        t = TextInput
        f = FloatLayout()
        s = Scatter()
        s.add_widget(l)
        l = Label(text="hell0",
                  font_size=50)
        f.add_widget(s)
        b.add_widget(f)
        b.add_widget(t)

        return b

Comment: @RomanV That's very hard to read in the comment format, and comments don't last. Comments on Stack Overflow are used for clarifying questions and answers, and are deleted once they're no longer needed - they're supposed to be temporary. Please *edit your original question* to include enough information for someone to try it themselves, so that they can work out what your problem might be. This includes a small piece of code that shows the problem - small and simple enough to remove anything unrelated, but large enough that someone can easily run it and see the same problem you're having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a `t = TextInput` which does not create a `TextInput` widget, so your `b.add_widget(t)` fails because `t` is not a widget. Just change `t = TextInput` to `t = TextInput()`. And if you are using `GridLayout`, you must specify either `cols` or `rows` in the call to `GridLayout()`.